# ESP32 Bluetooth secure BLE auto reconnect after Android comes back into range?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

kinda of a newbee here been bashing my head against the wall trying to figure out how to get esp32 BLE to automatically reconnect the an Android phone after the phone either turns the Bluetooth back ON or when the phone comes back into range of the esp32.

Is it even possible to do with esp32 and IDE? Here is what I have so far and it does what I want it, it pulls a pin HIGH when there is a secure connection, and where there isn’t a connection it pulls the pin goes LOW. Just need the auto reconnection to the phone to work

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>


BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;
#define SERVICE_UUID        "8c30f045-683a-4777-8d21-87def63e4ef5"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "e6eae575-4d89-4750-bf3e-c82d6a1cd299"
#define PASSKEY 999999

#define LED_BUILTIN 0


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  bleInit();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
  delay(1000);
}

/////////////////////
//BLE Secure Server//
/////////////////////

class ServerCallback: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      Serial.println(" - ServerCallback - onConnect");
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      Serial.println(" - ServerCallback - onDisconnect");
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
};

class SecurityCallback : public BLESecurityCallbacks {

    uint32_t onPassKeyRequest() {
      return 000000;
    }

    void onPassKeyNotify(uint32_t pass_key) {}

    bool onConfirmPIN(uint32_t pass_key) {
      vTaskDelay(5000);
      return true;
    }

    bool onSecurityRequest() {
      return true;
    }

    void onAuthenticationComplete(esp_ble_auth_cmpl_t cmpl) {
      if (cmpl.success) {
        Serial.println("   - SecurityCallback - Authentication Success");
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      } else {
        Serial.println("   - SecurityCallback - Authentication Failure*");
        pServer->removePeerDevice(pServer->getConnId(), true);
      }
      BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
    }
};

void bleSecurity() {
  esp_ble_auth_req_t auth_req = ESP_LE_AUTH_REQ_SC_MITM_BOND;
  esp_ble_io_cap_t iocap = ESP_IO_CAP_OUT;
  uint8_t key_size = 16;
  uint8_t init_key = ESP_BLE_ENC_KEY_MASK | ESP_BLE_ID_KEY_MASK;
  uint8_t rsp_key = ESP_BLE_ENC_KEY_MASK | ESP_BLE_ID_KEY_MASK;
  uint32_t passkey = PASSKEY;
  uint8_t auth_option = ESP_BLE_ONLY_ACCEPT_SPECIFIED_AUTH_DISABLE;
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_SET_STATIC_PASSKEY, &passkey, sizeof(uint32_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_AUTHEN_REQ_MODE, &auth_req, sizeof(uint8_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_IOCAP_MODE, &iocap, sizeof(uint8_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_MAX_KEY_SIZE, &key_size, sizeof(uint8_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_ONLY_ACCEPT_SPECIFIED_SEC_AUTH, &auth_option, sizeof(uint8_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_SET_INIT_KEY, &init_key, sizeof(uint8_t));
  esp_ble_gap_set_security_param(ESP_BLE_SM_SET_RSP_KEY, &rsp_key, sizeof(uint8_t));
}

void bleInit() {
  BLEDevice::init("BLE-Secure-Server");
  BLEDevice::setEncryptionLevel(ESP_BLE_SEC_ENCRYPT);
  BLEDevice::setSecurityCallbacks(new SecurityCallback());

  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new ServerCallback());

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                    );

  pCharacteristic->setAccessPermissions(ESP_GATT_PERM_READ_ENCRYPTED | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE_ENCRYPTED);
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();

  bleSecurity();
}
```

Comment: First, never use a static passkey with BLE security since that totally destroys the security (https://insinuator.net/2021/10/change-your-ble-passkey-like-you-change-your-underwear/). To your question: just let ESP32 advertise which will allow a new connection. Then use autoConnect=true on the Android side to automatically reconnect if connection is dropped when you call connectGatt. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67168220/556495 for more important details.